# How can I get a variables datatype in zsh?

Tags: zsh, variable

For example zsh uses the variable `$fpath` to define include directories.
How can I tell what type of variable `$fpath` is?
i.e. is `fpath` a

- string
- number
- numeric array
- associative array

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `t` parameter expansion flag:

```
$ print -rl -- ${(t)fpath}
array-special
$ a=1
$ print -rl -- ${(t)a}
scalar
$ a=(1 2)
$ print -rl -- ${(t)a}
array
$ typeset -A a
$ print -rl -- ${(t)a}
association
```

Note that you can't distinguish between array of integers or array of strings.

Comment: cool, I see from `man zshexpn` **parameter expansion flags** `(t)`  *Use a string describing the type of the parameter* . thanks cuonglm

Comment: You can distinguish between arrays of integers and arrays of strings: there are no arrays of integers, so if it's an array, it's an array of strings.

Comment: I don't think you need to use `print` and instead you can use `echo ${(t)a}`